# Node-Red Big SSH pass the credentials from other node.?

Tags: node-red

I am trying to pass the credentials and command from the other payload to the BIG-ssh node, but it is not considering the input, these credentials are coming from the user input, for now I have hardcoded into the inject node. Please refer the screenshot, How to solve this issue.?

[image]

Comment: Not all nodes allow configuration to be passed in, but a quick look at the source code fo the node (since there is no meaningful doc...) suggests that the connection details should be under `msg.config.uhcred` not `msg`.